# Drawing arbitrary shaped grids in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I would like to reproduce grids like the following (taken from [here](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/minesw/minesw.pdf), p.5):

[image: grid]

So far, I've come up with the following TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={
      rectangle,
      draw=black,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      align=center,
      text width=#1,
      text height=2ex,
      text depth=0.5ex,      
      inner sep=0pt,
    }    
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2em
}

\matrix[square matrix]
{
&&&&                      1 & 2       & 2       & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & 1    & 1   & 2 & $\star$ & $\star$ & 3       & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & $x'$ & $x$ & 2 & $x'$    & $\star$ & $\star$ & 2 \\
\ldots & 1 & 1    & 1   & 1 & 2       & $x$     & $\star$ & 2 \\
&&&&&                         1       & 2       & 2       & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & $x'$    & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & $x$     & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & 1       & 1 \\
&&&&&                         \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The following details are still missing:

- The `X->` labels
- The cells containing the dots should be open to one side

In addition, it would be nice to make the outer border a little bit thicker than the inner lines. Also, I'm not quite sure if I set the correct options for the nodes. They should be exact squares with equal baselines for the text inside.

If there's a totally different but easier way of drawing this whole thing, please tell me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect]

\tikzset{
  square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={
      rectangle,
      draw=gray,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      align=center,
      text width=#1,
      text height=2ex,
      text depth=0.5ex,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
    }
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2em
}

\matrix(m)[square matrix]
{
&&&&                      1 & 2       & 2       & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & 1    & 1   & 2 & $\star$ & $\star$ & 3       & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & $x'$ & $x$ & 2 & $x'$    & $\star$ & $\star$ & 2 \\
\ldots & 1 & 1    & 1   & 1 & 2       & $x$     & $\star$ & 2 \\
&&&&&                         1       & 2       & 2       & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & $x'$    & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & $x$     & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & 1       & 1 \\
&&&&&                         \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots \\
};
\draw[white,very thick] (m-9-6.south west) -- (m-9-8.south east);
\draw[white,very thick] (m-2-1.north west) -- (m-4-1.south west);
\draw[thick] (m-2-1.north west) -- (m-2-4.north east) -- (m-1-5.north west) -- (m-1-8.north east) --
            (m-1-8.south east) -- (m-2-9.north east) -- (m-5-9.south east) -- (m-5-9.south west) --
            (m-9-8.south east);
\draw[thick] (m-4-1.south west) -- (m-4-5.south east) -- (m-9-6.south west);
\node[anchor=south] (x) at (m-2-1.north east) {X};
\draw[->] (x.east) --  +(2em,0);
\node[anchor=west] (xx) at (m-7-8.east) {X};
\draw[->] (xx.south) --  +(0,-2em);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a alternative answer; it seems you want to do cellular automata. I like this following method for grids. It's very clear code and good looking, I think, but at once it gives you maximum control over every aspect and boundary combination. It's nicely combined with other methods. It does not require a matrix environment.

1)

You'll have to make a folder. You have 6 different tiles I see; you need to make 6 + 1 = 7 .tex document in that case.

Each of the tile documents has code of of this kind:

```
\documentclass{standalone}%
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}% this must be loaded prior \usepackage{tikz}
% general package
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
% specific package

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\Large]

\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (0,0) edge (0,1);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (0,1) edge (1,1);
\draw[dotted](0.5,0.5) node {$x$};
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (1,1) edge (1,0);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (1,0) edge (0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Simply replace the line parameters and the text inside $ ... $

Lets suppose you make two tiles, one called anicon.tex, the other ohicon.tex and compile them

The final main document is where you work:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}%
% general package
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
% specific package
\usepackage{float}

% a grid point
\def\gp#1#2{\node at (#1) {\includegraphics{\csname #2\endcsname}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

            \gp{0,4}{R}
            \gp{0,3}{x}\gp{1,3}{R}
\gp{-1,2}{R}\gp{0,2}{x}
            \gp{0,1}{R}\gp{1,1}{R}

\draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[solid](-1.5,0) node {$\textbf{F}$};
\draw[->,thick] (-1,3) -- (-2,3);
\draw[solid](-2.5,3) node {$\textbf{E}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{FIGURE CAPTION GOES HERE}
    \label{fig:FIGURE NAME GOES HERE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can very rapidly construct arbitrary and good looking automata diagrams

You can change color to white of any box side to make it transparent (or make a highlighted side) and recompile with a click and then a click in your main document. All boxes automatically update at once, so you don't have to change them manually if you decide to change a function rule.

[image: resulticon]

2)

If you want to, you can further save filesize and reduce number of files to 2 documents, and also reduce the amount you need to type to the minimum possible.

In this example, we have 4 different functions = 4 different boxes, but they are side by side in one file. Our texture file is named `iconset` and we crop parts of it and rearrange them in our `automata` file:

```
% iconset
\documentclass{standalone}%
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
% general package
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
% specific package

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\large]

\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (0,0) edge (0,1);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (0,1) edge (1,1);
\draw[dotted](0.5,0.5) node {$X$};
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (1,1) edge (1,0);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (1,0) edge (0,0);

\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (0,1) edge (0,2);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (0,2) edge (1,2);
\draw[dotted](0.5,1.5) node {$\textbf{a}$};
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (1,2) edge (1,1);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (1,1) edge (0,1);

\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (-1,1) edge (-1,2);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (-1,2) edge (0,2);
\draw[dotted](-0.5,1.5) node {$\textbf{b}$};
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (0,2) edge (0,1);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (0,1) edge (-1,1);

\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (-1,0) edge (-1,1);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,red,solid] (-1,1) edge (0,1);
\draw[dotted](-0.5,0.5) node {$Y$};
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (0,1) edge (0,0);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,black,solid] (0,0) edge (-1,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Our work figure is this file

```
% automata
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}%
% general package
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
% specific package
\usepackage{float}

% a grid point
\def\ai#1{\node at (#1) {%
    \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 10.1mm 10.1mm 0mm, clip]{iconset}};}
\def\bi#1{\node at (#1) {%
    \includegraphics[trim = 10.1mm 10.1mm 0mm 0mm, clip]{iconset}};}
\def\Yi#1{\node at (#1) {%
    \includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 10.1mm 10.1mm, clip]{iconset}};}
\def\Xi#1{\node at (#1) {%
    \includegraphics[trim = 10.1mm 0mm 0mm 10.1mm, clip]{iconset}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

          \Yi{0,4}
          \ai{0,3} \Xi{1,3}
\Xi{-1,2} \bi{0,2}
          \Xi{0,1} \bi{1,1}

\draw[->,thick] (-1,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[solid](-1.5,0) node {$\textbf{F}$};
\draw[->,thick] (-1,3) -- (-2,3);
\draw[solid](-2.5,3) node {$\textbf{E}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{FIGURE CAPTION GOES HERE}
    \label{fig:FIGURE NAME GOES HERE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This method is typically used in a game engine because it is the most processor efficient, requires least memory, has smallest filesize, and makes for the cleanest cost.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to present you my experiment. I have noticed this fine arbitrary shape problem when I read about Hexagon Mesh solved in D3js, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5249328. In this example, I tried to draw major border (used versus unused table cells), group cells according to their shown text, layer them and try one or two other things along the way. I am generating a TikZ picture from the original data in Lua which is loaded in TeX afterwards. I define styles at a TikZ level.

I use four basic layers (that's also an order of appearance): cells with text+fills, basic lines, lines forming groups and border lines. I define input data (`data`) and form several text groups (`types`). Dots (`\ldots` and `\vdots`) and unassigned texts (`Icu!`) are processed differently. Dots have one end of the cell opened, the unassigned text is typesetted before any other material. For layering I use ordering of typeset material only. I highlighted the last text group by white colour.

After splitting data to rows/columns/cells I am checking relations among cells. After that I am able to generate individual TikZ nodes and lines with their styles. The key element are lines between the cells. To be able to draw a perfect line in squares I am using correction of `0.5\pgflinewidth`. The generated code is rather large, but I wanted to try different approach.

This is the `mal-arbitrary.lua` file, which we process by `texlua mal-arbitrary.lua` command. The `mal-result.tikz` file is generated along the way which is loaded by TeX in `mal-basic.tex`. I enclose both the files and a preview of the resulting table.

```
data=[[
&&&&                      1 & 2       & 2       & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & 1    & 1   & 2 & $\star$ & $\star$ & 3       & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & $x'$ & $x$ & 2 & $x'$    & $\star$ & $\star$ & 2 \\
\ldots & 1 & 1    & 1   & 1 & 2       & $x$     & $\star$ & 2 \\
&&&&&                         Icu!       & 2       & 2       & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & $x'$    & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & $x$     & 1 \\
&&&&&                         1       & 1       & 1 \\
&&&&&                         \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots \\]]
--print(data)
types={ {"\\ldots"}, {"\\vdots"}, {"1"}, {"2"}, {"3"}, {"$\\star$"}, {"$x$","$x'$"} }   


print("I'm generating a TikZ file...")
-- Parsing data
data=string.gsub(data, "%s+", "")
data=string.gsub(data, "\\+$", "") -- delete \\ at the end of file
data=data.."\\\\" -- add \\ for later use
row=0
malmatrix={}
string.gsub(data, "(.-)\\\\", function (s)
   s=s.."&"
   --print(s)
   row=row+1; column=0
   string.gsub(s, "(.-)&", function (t)
      --io.write(t)
      column=column+1
      label=column.."-"..row
      if t~="" then malmatrix[label]={column,row,t} end
   end)
   --print(); print()
   end)

-- testing specific cell on-the-fly (ineffective?)
function testtype(cell)
for typesrow,maltype in pairs(types) do
for _,malcell in pairs(maltype) do
if malcell==cell then return typesrow end
end -- for
end -- for
return 100 -- not present
end -- function testype

function savefile()
tobesaved="\\draw["..bonus.."] ($("..k.."-"..l.."."..fromcorner..")+"..correctiona.."$) -- ($("..k.."-"..l.."."..tocorner..")+"..correctionb.."$);\n"
end

function testme(tempk, templ)
k=tempk; l=templ
for counter,pos in pairs{ {-1,0},{1,0},{0,-1},{0,1} } do
newx=k+pos[1]
newy=l+pos[2]
tested=malmatrix[newx.."-"..newy] -- watch for neighbours in four directions (west, east, south, north)
--print(k,l, newx,newy)
--if tested then print("",tested,tested[1], tested[2], tested[3]) end
celltype=testtype(malmatrix[k.."-"..l][3])

bonus="border"
if (celltype==1 and counter<=2) or (celltype==2 and counter>=3) then bonus="malwhite" end

veryextra=nil
if tested then 
   celltypeB=testtype(tested[3])  
if celltype~=celltypeB and celltype>2 then bonus="extra"..celltype  else bonus="commonline" end
else 
if celltype>2 then veryextra="extra"..celltype end
end

--if celltype=="x" then bonus="border" end

-- not effective, but it is doing its job
correctiona="(0,0.5\\pgflinewidth)"
correctionb="(0,-0.5\\pgflinewidth)"
if counter==1 then fromcorner="north west"; tocorner="south west" end -- right
if counter==2 then fromcorner="north east"; tocorner="south east" end -- left
   if counter>2 then 
   correctiona="(0.5\\pgflinewidth,0)"
   correctionb="(-0.5\\pgflinewidth,0)"
   end
if counter==3 then fromcorner="south east"; tocorner="south west" end -- below
if counter==4 then fromcorner="north east"; tocorner="north west" end -- above
savefile()

if not tested then -- no, there is an empty space
-- major border
forlater=forlater..tobesaved
else
if bonus~="commonline" then
forlatercommon=forlatercommon..tobesaved
else
saveme:write(tobesaved)
end -- if
end -- if
if veryextra then bonus=veryextra; savefile() end

end -- for
end -- of function testme


saveme=io.open("mal-result.tikz","w")
-- correction, flipping values
oldmatrix=malmatrix
malmatrix={}
for _,hodnota in pairs(oldmatrix) do
newvalue=row-oldmatrix[hodnota[1].."-"..hodnota[2]][2]+1
malmatrix[hodnota[1].."-"..newvalue]={hodnota[1],newvalue,hodnota[3]}
end
oldmatrix=nil

-- drawing nodes with fills, drawing is not necessary
for _,hodnota in pairs(malmatrix) do
saveme:write("\\node["..testtype(malmatrix[hodnota[1].."-"..hodnota[2]][3]).."] ("..hodnota[1].."-"..hodnota[2]..") at ("..hodnota[1]..","..hodnota[2]..") {"..hodnota[3].."};\n")
end

-- drawing inner lines
saveme:write("\n")
forlater=""
forlatercommon=""

-- unassigned nodes to be processed first, please
for _,hodnota in pairs(malmatrix) do
if testtype(hodnota[3])==100 then 
    testme(hodnota[1], hodnota[2])
    end -- if
end -- of for, malmatrix

-- simple simulation/handling of layering node types
for layer=1,#types do
for _,hodnota in pairs(malmatrix) do
if testtype(hodnota[3])==layer then -- that's not effective, it is computed on-the-fly several times
    testme(hodnota[1], hodnota[2])
    end -- if
end -- of for, malmatrix
end -- of for, layer

-- drawing inner lines
saveme:write("\n"..forlatercommon)

-- drawing borders
saveme:write("\n"..forlater)

-- finish the job
saveme:close()
```

This is the TeX file processed by any major LaTeX engine, e.g. `lualatex mal-basic.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\def\malwidth{7.7mm}
\def\mallinewidth{3pt}
\def\mallinewidthb{1.5pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum width=\malwidth, minimum height=\malwidth, draw=none, text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex}, x=\malwidth, y=\malwidth, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, 
   border/.style={line width=\mallinewidth, red, draw},
   malwhite/.style={line width=\mallinewidth, white},
   commonline/.style={draw=brown}, % try none
   100/.style={fill=brown},
   1/.style={fill=none},
   2/.style={fill=none},
   3/.style={fill=cyan},
   4/.style={fill=magenta},
   5/.style={fill=orange},
   6/.style={fill=yellow},
   7/.style={fill=green},
extra100/.style={line width=\mallinewidthb},
extra3/.style={line width=\mallinewidthb},
extra4/.style={line width=\mallinewidthb},
extra5/.style={line width=\mallinewidthb},
extra6/.style={line width=\mallinewidthb},
extra7/.style={line width=\mallinewidthb,white},
   ]
\input mal-result.tikz
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arbitrary shape: a result of our efforts]